# C passing a string containing a file path to main()

Tags: c, string, parameter-passing, filepath

I want to pass a string that contains a file path

```
/home/bin/example.txt
```

from

```
char path[50];
char passpath()
{
// do something
// ...
return(path); 
}
```

to my main function.
In passpath()

```
printf("%s\n", path);
```

gives the right path back (`/home/bin/example.txt`). Bun when I try the same in my main function the first "/" is missing and `printf("%s\n", path);` results (in eclipse) in

```
(some unresolved sign with "?" in it)home/bin/example.txt
```

what went wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Right now it's impossible to understand what's happening and therefore all answers will just be guesses.

Comment: What is the content of passpath()?

Comment: But a good staring point might be what happens when you try to return a string in a function declared to return a single character. If it doesn't give you a build error, it should at least give you a warning. Warnings are just as important to fix as errors, as many warnings are indicators of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which will cause your program to behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `dynamic allocations`. It is very common in C.
Remove the `char path[50];` line at the beginning and ***inside*** your `passpath()` function do the following.

```
char *path = malloc(50);
strcpy(path, "/home/bin/example.txt");
return path;
```

Comment: Please don't recommend folks to use `sizeof (char)`, it just adds confusion. The size of `char` is always 1.

Comment: Just wanted to make things correctly but ok I get it :)

Comment: when I try this I get an error:
initializer element is not constant (in the allocation)

Comment: @smaica that goes in a function body, not at file scope.

Comment: Indeed place the code inside the function

Comment: Also change the function type to char*